# automatic Samba share script

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, samba, network-drive

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server running Samba.

I want to write a script (for Linux or Windows computer) that, given the IP of this server and the path of the shared Samba folder, can automatically create a "network drive" icon on the desktop. Both machines are on a local network.

I realize this will be different for linux/windows.

Any suggestions? I'm just not sure where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows machines, you want to look at `net use`. For instance, to map the share "Data" on 192.168.0.2 to Z:, you'd write `net use Z: \\192.168.0.2\Data`. There is a lot of options, so check `net help use` for a complete list. For instance, you might want to look at `/persistent`, which would automatically recreate the share every time you log in.
Or you could put this in a .BAT file which is executed when logging in.

On linux, I think you'd generally have to be root to do this, as it'd require a `mount` command. I know some desktop environments (such as GNOME) get around this, but to acually mount it you need root. The command to mount the same share at the mountpoint `/mnt/Data` would simply be `mount //192.168.0.2/Data /mnt/Data`, if you allow anyone access. If you require a logon, you need to add `-o User=YOURUSER`. You will then be prompted for a password.
(Note that this requires the CIFS/SMB drivers to work)